# Upgrading from Windows Azure Storage Client Library 2.1 to 3.0

Tags: azure, migration, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm upgrading a project from .NET MVC 4.0 to 5.0.  Mostly just upgrading NuGet packages has worked without changes to the code; however, there appear to be some rather large changes when upgrading the Azure Storage Client.

I now have a ton of build errors - the BlobRequestOptions class seems to have lost several members like the DeleteSnapshotsOption and UseFlatBlobOption members, and CloudBlobContainer no longer has the function CreateIfNotExists.

Does anyone know of a migration guide for upgrading from previous Azure Storage Client versions to 3.0?  Or maybe I'm missing something dumb and easy?

Comment: Actually I'm upgrading all the way from Azure Storage v 1.7 to 3 (skipping 2 - apparently there were a lot of changes from 1.7-2).  I may try to reinstall 1.7 and keep the rest of the project at MVC 5.0

Comment: I found some good tutorials about migrating from 1.7 to 2.0 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/10/29/windows-azure-storage-client-library-2-0-breaking-changes-amp-migration-guide.aspx - but ended up simply reverting to 1.7 since it was just one change out of many to get to MVC 5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration guide from 1.7 to 2.0 should help you with the migration. Although we have a few breaking changes in 3.0(listed [here](https://github.com/wastore/StorageClientPrivate/blob/master/BreakingChanges.txt)), there should not be any major change between 2.0 and 3.0. Please let us know if you have any issues upgrading to the latest 3.X version and we can help.

We strongly encourage you to upgrade to the latest version because it includes a ton of new features, broader platform compatibility, better performance and revisions to address the great feedback that customers have given us over time. In addition to that, the 3.X libraries also support the 2013-08-15 Storage REST version that introduced [all these great features](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx).

Comment: The listed "here" link above is broken. There are definitely breaking changes. The namespace for the CloudConfigurationManager has changed from Microsoft.WindowsAzure to Microsoft.Azure for example. I'm looking for a list of the rest still.